# Python pandas datetime attribute extraction

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data set has datetime data, I want to iterate over each day and run some function on one of the attributes for each day.
How do i iterate over each day in datetime series?

So, I am iterating using groupby(Date)

Index    Date         Time

1       2-12-2018     13:22:27 \n

I need a way to tell if the time is between 12am to 6 am or other time intervals.
Time is an object here. I am new to python and pandas

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Glen, welcome to SO! As it stands, your question is pretty general, which means that it is hard to give a precise answer. Please have a look at [ask] and [mre]. Especially the latter would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the date from the datetime data, considering a dataframe `df` with `mydate` as the datetime type column you can do this:

```
df['day'] = df.mydate.dt.day
```

`df['day']` will be a pandas series with Integer type (int64) values.

Answer (score 0):

I used,
`set_index('DateTime').between_time('00:00', '06:00', include_end=False).reset_index()`

to further classify my dataframe into required data frame.